# How to reliably restore MySQL blobs

Tags: mysql, backup, blob, restore

I have been backing up a MySQL database for several years with the command:
`mysqldump  myDatabaseName -u root > myBackupFile.sql`

The backups have appeared to work fine...

I then wanted to restore one of the backups to a different named database so I did:
`mysql  myNewDatabaseName -u root < myBackupFile.sql`

I got some errors about logfile size so I stopped Mysql and removed the logfiles and set the following parameters in the my.ini file and restarted mysql.

`innodb_log_file_size=64M`

`innodb_log_buffer_size=8M`

The restore now completes with no errors but one of the three tables which contains blobs is never restored.

My `max-allowed-packet` is set to 32M

The database backup size is about 2.2 GB the majority of that size being in the table that does not restore. If I run a mysqldump on the restored database the size is 185 MB.

I have now tried doing a `mysqldump` with the option `--hex-blob` but I have not tried to restore that file (3.9 GB) yet.

I really need to have a bombproof way to backup and restore as my existing backups appear worthless. I am particularly concerned that it "fails silently" with no error log entries as far as I can see.

The environment is windows server 2003 sp2

Any help appreciated!

George

Comment: Are the blobs present in the dump file? Perhaps they were never backed up to begin with and the restore process worked perfectly with what data there actually was. The max_packet affects data going both ways. If you dumped with too small a limit, the blobs may have been dropped or truncated.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to back up and restore the blobs by using the following mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump --opt  --skip-extended-insert --max_allowed_packet=128M -u root myDB > filename
```

Not sure if it’s specifying `max_allowed_packet` on the command line or the `skip-extended-insert` that did the trick.

I assumed that my `max_allowed_packet` of 32M was being used, but I think that in the mysql config file it is in the [mysqld] section and so probably does not apply to dump.

I still don’t understand why I got no errors on either the dump or the restore.

Comment: mysqldump ignores max_allowed_packet.  Read this bug report to try to figure out if it's by design or not: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9753

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump --skip-extended-insert` works but can reduce performance by 100x on restore, making it not a viable choice.

When you do the backup, `max_allowed_packet` is ignored by `mysqldump` (by [design](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9753)?)  The actual complement is `net_buffer_length`.  So make sure your `max_allowed_packet` is bigger than your `net_buffer_length` and it should work.  As in:

```
mysqldump -u root --net_buffer_length=100k oldDB > backup.sql
mysql -u root --max_allowed_packet=10M newDB < backup.sql
```