# Imported blobs NULL

Tags: mysql

I started researching this with [How to reliably restore MySQL blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489437/how-to-reliably-restore-mysql-blobs) and [How can i dump blob fields from mysql tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139345/how-can-i-dump-blob-fields-from-mysql-tables)

I am exporting with

```
mysqldump -h otherhost -u myuser -p --net_buffer_length=256M oldDB > backup.sql
```

Then scp-ing the 50M file to new server and importing with

```
mysql -h myhost -u myuser --max_allowed_packet=600M -p mydb < backup.sql
```

I also tried the exports with `--opt --skip-extended-insert` added.

All of my imports result in full recordset with NULLs in the blob field.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How to prevent mysqldump from splitting dumps into 1MB increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634017/how-to-prevent-mysqldump-from-splitting-dumps-into-1mb-increments) I tried it this way with `--hex-blob`:

```
mysqldump --net_buffer_length=4096 --create-options --default-character-set="utf8" --host="myhost" --port="3308" --hex-blob --lock-tables -p --quote-names --user="myusr" "mydb" "mytable" > backup.sql

mysql -h othrhost -u otherusr --max_allowed_packet=600M -p otherdb < backup.sql
```

This method succeeded in porting the blobs without corruption.